# Combining insertion sort and merge sort

Tags: sorting, optimization

I was thinking of optimizing the current sorting algorithms. To make the process faster, I thought of using threads and divide the arrays into two parts. Sort that both arrays using insertion sort simultaneously using threads and wait for both of them to complete. After that use bubble sort to merge both of that array. Do you think, using this algorithm, the sorting will be faster ?

Comment: I have only thought of this right now. I will try to implement it today/tomorrow in C#, and will try to benchmark it myself. I was very curious, so posted the question if anyone has theoretical idea about it

Comment: Bubble sort will be a slow merge. Try bubble sorting the small lists then mergesorting them.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean By bubble sort I mean suppose I have two sorted array 
A [1,2,3,6,8,9,16] and B [4,7,10,11,13,15] obtained from using insertion sort and both running as threads. I will keep min and max of both of the array and will start with having minimum of the min value upto it fits. And then will loop until any of the array gets exhausted.

Comment: That second phase is called merging, not bubble sort. It is similar to what merge sort is doing. Maybe you can edit the question to fix this terminology. "Combining Insertion Sort and Merge Sort"

Answer (score 1):

No, that will not be faster, in the general case. Imagine, for example, that your initial array looks like this:

```
[9,5,7,6,8,3,2,0,4,1]
```

After sorting the two halves it looks like this:

```
[5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4]
```

Sorting that with bubble sort won't be appreciably faster than sorting the initial array with bubble sort. Total time elapsed with the insertion sorts plus the bubble sort almost certainly will be more than if you just sorted the initial array with a single thread.

Neither bubble sort nor insertion sort are particularly amenable to parallelization. You're better off implementing a parallel quicksort. Or, if you insist on using insertion sort in the threads, use a merge to combine the sorted sub-arrays. Of course, the merge would require O(n) additional memory.

Comment: Yes you are right. 
So now If I do something like this,
A=[5,6,7,8,9], B= [0,1,2,3,4], I will keep Amin and Bmin.  
Compare both of them and will check which have bigger value.  
Then I can go through each of the former array (having lower min value) and compare with latter one, and keep pushing the value where it fits until any one of the array gets exhausted

Answer (score 0):

No. Your method would not be faster than *known* methods of parallel sorting algorithms. Insertion sort is `O(n^2)`, and if applied would not result in better result unless the code is more *parallelised*. Given I assume you have only `two` threads to optimize : best will be to use `Merge sort` with two threads, which would help in Worst Case to be `O(nlogn)`. I dont know why you want to learn two thread parallelism, but learning from  the following resource might get you the knack of parallel algorithms of sorting in multithreads :
http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~fds/aulas/PPD/1112/sorting.pdf